# How do I have a seperate padding for groupbox header and groupbox content

Tags: wpf, xaml, margin, groupbox

I have a groupbox, but I want to had a padding of 5 all around the header, but no margin around the content.

How would I best go about this? I can't seem to find a way to seperate the padding values from each other...

Comment: Can you provide anything that you have tried already? Perhaps a picture of what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here a simple example

```
    <GroupBox Height="100" Width="200">
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="HEADER" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
    </GroupBox>
```